# how to make network graph easy to read

Tags: igraph

[the hard to read graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YCZK.jpg)
Here is the network graph I made using the code bellows,but it's extremely hard to read.Is there anyway to make it easier to read? And how to avoid the overlaps of edges and labels?

```
l<-layout.random(wcen_graph)
plot.igraph(wcen_graph,vertex.shape="circle",layout=l,
            edge.arrow.size=0.06,edge.width=E(wcen_graph)$Weight,
            vertex.label.dist=-0.3)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone help?Thanksss

Comment: First of all, do you need the loops? If not, remove them with `simplify()`. Then, use a different layout algorithm. I would start with `layout.fruchterman.reingold()` but take a look at `?layout.random` for other alternatives.